# ReactJS - How To Setup 3 Divs One On-Top Of The Other?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

**Disclaimer:**

- I'm new to `ReactJS`, and web-development as a whole. Did my best to research before, and did not find an answer.
- I'm probably missing something simple, but can't figure it out - so sorry if this question's answer is a one liner "How-Did-I-Miss-That' sort of answer.
- Feel free to comment/answer with best practices I missed, or things I can improve in this question.
- Thanks is advance to anybody that reads this!

**My Own Research:**

1. [Float 3 Divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58950408/float-3-divs-one-on-the-top-of-another) - I did not need the z-axis property, as non of my `div`s are on top of the other.
2. [3 Divs LTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div) - Talks about 3 divs aligned horizontally, not vertically. The same method did not work for me in the vertical axis.
3. [3 Divs LTR #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css) - This talks about `flex`, so I tried it too. In the right direction, but not enough.
4. [Vertical Align etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/how-to-vertical-align-elements-in-a-div?rq=1) - could not make it happen with this solution either.
5. (5... 1000) A bunch of other first-second-third results in Google search queries like: "ReactJS vertical 3 divs" and the likes.

**Actual Question:**

Trying to make a basic outline of a mockup web-page, which consists of 3 `div`s:

1. **Header Div** - In The Top, Not Sticky (=when you y axis scroll, it does not appear).
2. **Content Div** - In The Middle, Y/X Axis Scrollable.
3. **Bottom Nav Div** - In The Bottom, Sticky.

**Mockup:**

[image: Mockup]

**My Current Status:**

- Can't make my bottom-menu `div` to appear. it's stuck under the frame.
- Can't be sure my bottom-menu `div` is actually sticky because of the point above.
- The contents tab `div` has no margin from the Header `div`, which makes the upper end of the text in it - unreadble.

[image]

**My Code:**

Did a lot of back-and-fourth on this, and this is the closest version I have for this simple (yet - not working!) task:

**App.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import BottomMenu from "../BottomMenu/BottomMenu";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import ContentTab from "../ContentTab/ContentTab";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div style = {{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", overflow: "visible",
    direction: "rtl"}}>
      <Header/>
      <ContentTab />
      <BottomMenu />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Header.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Toolbar, AppBar } from "@material-ui/core";
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const Header = props => {

  return (
        <div>
          <AppBar color="primary" style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Toolbar>
              <Typography>
                Test
              </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**ContentTab.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const ContentTab = (props) => {
    return (
        <div style={{height: "80%", width: "100%"}}>
            <Paper align="center" elevation={3}>
                <Typography paragraph>First</Typography>
                <Typography paragraph>TextTab</Typography>
                <Typography paragraph>Last</Typography>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ContentTab;
```

**BottomMenu.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import BottomNavigation from "@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation";
import BottomNavigationAction from "@material-ui/core/BottomNavigationAction";
import RestoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Restore";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import LocationOnIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LocationOn";
import { Toolbar, AppBar } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function BottomMenu() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    return (
        <div style={{
            position: "fixed", bottom: "0", width: "100%", height: "10%"}}>
            <AppBar
                style={{ background: '#FFFFFF', alignItems: "center" }}
            >
                <Toolbar>
                    <BottomNavigation
                        value={value}
                        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                            setValue(newValue);
                        }}
                        showLabels
                    >
                        <BottomNavigationAction label="Recents" icon={<RestoreIcon />} />
                        <BottomNavigationAction label="Favorites" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
                        <BottomNavigationAction label="Nearby" icon={<LocationOnIcon />} />
                    </BottomNavigation>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually; the issue is that you're using the Material-UI component AppBar. If this were just a regular DIV tag then you could position it the way you want. To use the AppBar component and make it do what you what then this should do the trick:

- remove the outer DIV on the BottomMenu component
- style the BottomMenu component's appBar with top of auto and bottom of 0 and give it a position property of fixed.
- additionally, style the Header component's appBar with position of static.

this:
in BottomMenu:

```
<AppBar
      position="fixed"
      style={{
        top: "auto",
        bottom: "0",
        background: "#FFFFFF",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
    >
```

in Header:

```
  <AppBar
    position="static"
    color="primary"
    style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
  >
```

Here's a link to the docs that show it doing what you want:
https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/

and here's a link to a code sandbox with your code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-with-bottom-appbar-ugk31

In general, what I've found with Material-UI is that some of their components have positioning logic built into them and you need to use their properties for positioning instead of trying to do it with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Managed to make it sticky. :) The only thing missing in your answer is the third point I mentioned - how to make the ContentTab in the middle, so the upper and bottom part of the text won’t be hidden...

Comment: didn't notice that at first; it's the other app bar. It needs position="static". Editing answer to note.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!